# I don't understand this syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax

I just ran into this syntax in my studies. Does a space before and after values indicate that I can pass multiple values into this argument?

```
def no_odds( values )
```

Comment: no it doesn't.. `*values` does

Comment: Is this just Ruby's flexible syntax at work? ( values ) == (values)?

Comment: The parentheses around a method's arguments are optional; your convention is to use them when a method has arguments and omit them when it doesn't.

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev If you mean method definition/declaration, it is probably truth. In cases of *using* methods, not always: `def arr a, b; end; arr 2,3 {puts 42} #SyntaxError: unexpected '{', expecting $end
arr 2,3 {puts 42}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Spaces are simply *allowed* in argument lists.

```
# all identical
def foo(bar,baz); end
def foo(bar, baz); end
def foo( bar, baz ); end
def foo( bar , baz ); end
```

No magic here, just style.  And most ruby I've seen uses the `def foo(bar, baz)` style.

Comment: As fair I remember, spaces are deleted.